# How to get instance id for docker host in cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a simple CloudFormation stack which gets created with a template. A server which hosts one Docker container.

This is part of the template that creates the host and the container:

```
  ContainerHostInstances:
    Type: "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"
    DependsOn: "AttachGateway"
    Properties:
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
      ImageId: "ami-0302f3ec240b9d23c"
      SecurityGroups:
        - Ref: "NginxSecurityGroup"
      InstanceType: "t3.nano"
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref "ECSHostEC2InstanceProfile"
      KeyName: "test-key-pair"
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          echo ECS_CLUSTER=${MyCluster} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
          yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource ECSAutoScalingGroup --region ${AWS::Region}

...

  MyTask:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition"
    Properties:
      Family: "my-task-family"
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: "nginx"
          Essential: true
          Image: "image_url/nginx:latest"
          MemoryReservation: 300
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: "awslogs"
            Options:
              awslogs-group: "nginx"
              awslogs-region: !Ref "AWS::Region"
              awslogs-stream-prefix: "prefix"
              awslogs-datetime-format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L"
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 80
              HostPort: 80
```

My problem is that I can't associate an elastic IP address within the template. I can do it using the console but I want to have it inside the template if possible.

I tried this way:

```
  ElasticIPAssoc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation
    Properties:
      AllocationId: "some_id"
      InstanceId: "HOW CAN I GET THIS VALUE"
      NetworkInterfaceId: "OR THAT VALUE"
```

I don't see a way to get the instanceId or its corresponding NetworkInterfaceId.

Comment: I asked the same question on serverfault.com (which was probably what I should have done initially) and I got an answer there.

Comment: Hi, since that one has an answer, you may delete this one.

Comment: Answer here https://serverfault.com/questions/959096/how-to-get-instance-id-for-docker-host-in-cloudformation-template